# Which is correct pluralization "event planners" or "events planners"?

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english

The context is as follows, "We are an authoritative source of information dedicated to the needs of events planners in Asia"

Should it be events planners or event planners? 
Our editor claimed that events planners is correct, although I believe it should be event planners in this context.

I am american and she is British, could this be a British thing?

Answer (score 1):

Your editor is wrong. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=event%20planners%2C%20events%20planners&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cevent%20planners%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bevent%20planners%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEvent%20Planners%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEvent%20planners%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEVENT%20PLANNERS%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevents%20planners%3B%2Cc0) shows that the incidence of "events planners" is negligible. The preferred form is "event planners".

If I set out my shingle as an *event planner*, it doesn't follow that I plan just one event. I plan *events* as my profession. So it's somewhat odd to say that the singular *event* is appropriate for one person, but for multiple people it should be *events planners*.

Consider similar locutions like *animal doctor*, *bicycle repairman*, *language teacher*. Would your editor insist on *animals doctors*, *bicycles repairmen*, or *languages teachers*?

Comment: Though I suppose if you said *math teacher*, she would insist on *maths teachers* 

Comment: Is there any way you can elaborate on this? Exactly why is it wrong to have double plurals? Is there a rule that exists somewhere that explicitly says this? I only ask, not to argue with you, but I know that my editor will want some hard evidence to support the claim that what she thinks is wrong. Because we both think we are correct but there really isn't anything on the internet that explicitly says either way

Comment: I've already provided an Ngram. If your editor isn't convinced by that, or by the analogous examples of "language teacher", etc, then you should get a new editor.

Comment: She says that these examples you provided are wrong and she agrees with you. However, in this situation she insists that her using "events planners" is correct because it is an "industry specific" and "industry standard" word.

Comment: If it were an industry standard word, one would expect it to be used by those in the industry. Google Ngrams shoes it isn't.